# What is pyspark driver?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I saw that a common setup to start pyspark is using `pyspark --master yarn --deploy-mode client --num-executors 4 --executor-memory 2g --driver-memory 4g`, but how does driver memory differ from the executory memory? Could you please explain what a driver is and how does setting it here affects the pyspark workflow/performance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Spark uses a master/slave architecture. As you can see in the figure, it has one central coordinator (Driver) that communicates with many distributed workers (executors). The driver and each of the executors run in their own Java processes.

DRIVER

The driver is the process where the main method runs. First it converts the user program into tasks and after that it schedules the tasks on the executors.

EXECUTORS

Executors are worker nodes' processes in charge of running individual tasks in a given Spark job. They are launched at the beginning of a Spark application and typically run for the entire lifetime of an application. Once they have run the task they send the results to the driver. They also provide in-memory storage for RDDs that are cached by user programs through Block Manager.

Answer (score 0):

A `Spark Driver` is the process of running the `main()` function of the application and creating the `SparkContext`.

`--driver-memory` setup the memory used by this driver. If you run your application in client mode, this will most probably be the max-memory use by the Master Node. The master node is only used to coordinate jobs between the executors, so he's not really used to do any computation. 
The memory in the Driver can be filled calling an operation an `Action` like [collect](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.collect) that return a list that contains all of the elements in this RDD. If the RDD is bigger than the driver memory, the Spark Application will through an `OutOfMemory` error.

Here you can find more information about Spark components: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html#components

Answer (score 0):

This is a wonderful link describing the various parameters for tuning spark applications.
It includes description for `driver memory`, `executor memory`, etc.
http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-1/
http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/

[Spark Job Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E21xD.png)

> A Spark application consists of a single driver process and a set of executor processes scattered across nodes on the cluster.
>
> The driver is the process that is in charge of the high-level control flow of work that needs to be done. The executor processes are responsible for executing this work, in the form of tasks, as well as for storing any data that the user chooses to cache. Both the driver and the executors typically stick around for the entire time the application is running, although dynamic resource allocation changes that for the latter. A single executor has a number of slots for running tasks, and will run many concurrently throughout its lifetime. Deploying these processes on the cluster is up to the cluster manager in use (YARN, Mesos, or Spark Standalone), but the driver and executor themselves exist in every Spark application.